# Efficiently add noise to all trainable weights in a model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

How can I efficiently access all trainable variables of a Keras model within a `tf.fuction` to add custom noise to **all** variables?

Let's assume this simple model:

```py
my_model = Sequential()
my_model.add(Dense(300, input_dim=40, activation='relu'))
my_model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
my_model.add(Dense(8, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Running eagerly, I can do this by:

```py
@tf.function
def weight_perturbation(model, generator):
    n_layers = len(model.layers)

    # iterate over all layers
    for i in tf.range(n_layers):
        trainable_weights = model.layers[i].trainable_variables

        # iterate over all weight vectors in a layer 
        for j in tf.range(len(trainable_weights)):
            trainable_weights[j].assign_add(generator.normal(tf.shape(trainable_weights[j]), dtype=tf.float64))
```

However, when not running eagerly, I get the following error:

```py
     trainable_weights = model.layers[i].trainable_variables

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Tensor
```

How can I circumvent this problem? I had a look at `tf.gather` but this does not seem to work with lists.

The best would be, if there is a way to get all trainable weights of a model as a flattened tensor without looping. Unfortunately, I haven't found anything like this.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me if I iterate through the layers and weights rather than iterating through `tf.range`:

```
def weight_perturbation(model):
    for layer in model.layers:
        trainable_weights = layer.trainable_variables

        for weight in trainable_weights :
            random_weights = tf.random.uniform(tf.shape(weight), 
                                               1e-4, 1e-5, dtype=tf.float32)
            weight.assign_add(random_weights)
```

I changed your data type to `tf.float32`, as it should be in most cases. I added the weight manipulation here:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras as K
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, Dense, MaxPooling2D, Dropout
from tensorflow import nn as nn
from functools import partial

(xtrain, ytrain), (xtest, ytest) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((xtrain, ytrain))
test = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((xtest, ytest))

def prepare(inputs, outputs):
    inputs = tf.cast(inputs, tf.float32)
    inputs = tf.divide(x=inputs, y=255)
    inputs = tf.expand_dims(inputs, -1)
    targets = tf.one_hot(outputs, depth=10)
    return inputs, targets

train = train.map(prepare).batch(64)
test = test.map(prepare).batch(64)

class MyCNN(K.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyCNN, self).__init__()
        Conv = partial(Conv2D, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation=nn.relu)
        MaxPool = partial(MaxPooling2D, pool_size=(2, 2))

        self.conv1 = Conv(filters=8)
        self.maxp1 = MaxPool()
        self.conv2 = Conv(filters=8)
        self.maxp2 = MaxPool()
        self.flatt = Flatten()
        self.dens1 = Dense(8, activation=nn.relu)
        self.drop1 = Dropout(.5)
        self.dens2 = Dense(10, activation=nn.softmax)

    def call(self, x, training=None, **kwargs):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.maxp1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.maxp2(x)
        x = self.flatt(x)
        x = self.dens1(x)
        x = self.drop1(x)
        x = self.dens2(x)
        return x

model = MyCNN()

loss_object = tf.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)

def compute_loss(model, x, y, training):
  out = model(inputs=x, training=training)
  loss = loss_object(y_true=y, y_pred=out)
  return loss, out

def get_grad(model, x, y):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss, out = compute_loss(model, x, y, training=False)
    return loss, tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables), out

def weight_perturbation(model):
    for layer in model.layers:
        trainable_weights = layer.trainable_variables

        for weight in trainable_weights :
            random_weights = tf.random.uniform(tf.shape(weight),
                                               1e-4, 1e-5, dtype=tf.float32)
            weight.assign_add(random_weights)

optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam()

verbose = "Epoch {:2d} Loss: {:.3f} TLoss: {:.3f} Acc: {:.3%} TAcc: {:.3%}"

for epoch in range(1, 10 + 1):
    train_loss = tf.metrics.Mean()
    train_acc = tf.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()
    test_loss = tf.metrics.Mean()
    test_acc = tf.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()

    weight_perturbation(model)

    for x, y in train:
        loss_value, grads, out = get_grad(model, x, y)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
        train_loss.update_state(loss_value)
        train_acc.update_state(y, out)

    for x, y in test:
        loss_value, _, out = get_grad(model, x, y)
        test_loss.update_state(loss_value)
        test_acc.update_state(y, out)

    print(verbose.format(epoch,
                         train_loss.result(),
                         test_loss.result(),
                         train_acc.result(),
                         test_acc.result()))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and sorry for my late reply. Since you are iterating over two lists, this would run as normal Python code and would not be optimized by AutoGraph. Take a look at the [reference](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/autograph/g3doc/reference/control_flow.md#while-statements).

Comment: `model.weights` returns a list so I'm not sure how one would proceed differently. It is a good question

Comment: maybe there is a way to create a new ```tf.Variable``` by concatenating all training variables in the network and work on that one instead. However, concatenating produces always tensors. And creating a new variable from that tensor would result in a copy of the training variables...